# called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer for a report() function

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a program that will calculate retail prices when the user enters an item's wholesale and markup percentage. I'm sure everything is correct except for line #15 where "double report = report(retailPrice)" where it gives the error `called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer for a report() function`.

I tried renaming pretty much all of the report variables and even the function to something different but it still results in the exact same error. It seems to work fine when completely omitting the report() function and replacing it with just a cout statement in main() but unfortunately the assignment requires it regardless of how pointless it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double getWholeSale();
double getMarkup();
double calculateRetail(double, double);
double report();

int main()
{
    double wholeSale = getWholeSale();
    double markup = getMarkup();
    double retailPrice = calculateRetail(markup, wholeSale);
    double report = report(retailPrice);
    cout << report;

    return 0;
}
//**************************
double getWholeSale()
{
    double wholeSale;
    cout << "Enter the item's wholesale: ";
    cin >> wholeSale;
    while (wholeSale < 0)
    {
        cout << "Wholesale must be a positive number: ";
        cin >> wholeSale;
    }
    return wholeSale;
}
//**************************
double getMarkup()
{
    double markup;
    cout << "Enter the item's markup percentage: ";
    cin >> markup;
    while (markup < 0)
    {
        cout << "Markup percentage must be a positive number: ";
        cin >> markup;
    }
    return markup;
}
//*************************
double calculateRetail(double markup, double wholeSale)
{
    double retailPrice;
    double markupPercentage = markup / 100;
    retailPrice = (wholeSale * markupPercentage) + wholeSale;
    return retailPrice;
}
//*************************
double report(double retailPrice)
{
    cout << "The retail price is: $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << retailPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `report` like:

```
double report = report(retailPrice);
```

You implement `report` like:

```
double report(double retailPrice)
```

But you declare `report` like:

```
double report();
```

One of these is not like the others ;) Fix your declaration to include a `double` parameter.